# Subscription for ORDER_STATUS_CHANGE and REPORT_PROCESSING_FINISHED. But no message is sent to SQS

Tags: amazon-web-services

i am working on NotificationApi. I've done everything according to the documentation. And I create Subscription for ORDER_STATUS_CHANGE and REPORT_PROCESSING_FINISHED. But no message is sent to SQS.

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Id": "Policy1323232328",
"Statement": [
{
"Sid": "Stmt1644349937",
"Effect": "Allow",
"Principal": {
"AWS": [
"arn:aws:iam::MYID:user/myuser",
"arn:aws:iam::MYID:root"
]
},
"Action": [
"sqs:GetQueueAttributes",
"sqs:SendMessage"
],
"Resource": "arn:aws:sqs:us-east-1:MYID:MYSQS"
}
]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Incredibly, you must use 437568002678 to set the Principal. I always thought the value 437568002678 was an example and used the value of my own AWS account. It seem was a fix value.So just follow [notifications-api-v1-use-case-guide](https://developer-docs.amazon.com/sp-api/docs/notifications-api-v1-use-case-guide#step-1-grant-selling-partner-api-permission-to-write-to-your-sqs-queue)